# Is there a particular coding standard with comments between function name and body?

Tags: php, coding-standards, comments

I'm integrating with a shipping API built in php.

They have a strange coding standard where the comments are between the function name and the first curly bracket.. which - subjectively - makes the code really hard to read.

Is this a particular, albeit non-standard, commenting standard?

Here's an example of a such a function

```
public function qualityControlDescription($qcCode)
/*
Converts a Quality Control code (e.g. 'U') to a descriptive string.
Input parameters (case-insensitive):
    $qcCode = a Quality Control code, as returned by invokeWebService

Returned:
    Description string (e.g. 'UNSERVICEABLE'), or "" if not found
*/
{
    if (is_null($qcCode))
    {
        return "";
    }
    $descriptionMap = $this->qualityControlDescriptionMap();
    $returnVal = $descriptionMap[strtoupper($qcCode)];
    if (is_null($returnVal))
    {
        $returnVal = "";
    }
    return $returnVal;
}
```

Comment: I do not believe this is a standard way of commenting. I believe the standard way is more like how javadoc understands comment blocks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP code tends to use a block before the function:

```
/**
 * Is the given array an associative array?
 */

function isAssoc($arr) {
    return array_keys($arr) !== range(0, count($arr) - 1);
}
```

I have seen much C, Java, JavaScript, Perl, and other code that uses a similar block-before-function style. However other languages (Python comes to mind most quickly) do use this "between the definition and the code" style. E.g.:

```
def is_string(s):
    """
    Is the given value `s` a string type?
    """
    return isinstance(s, (str, unicode))
```

There are a number of other conventions that tend to be language- and/or documentation-system specific for documenting the types, purposes, and default values for parameters and return types.

So that style is idiosyncratic for the PHP community, but not out of bounds considering all common documentation styles.

Here is [more on the PHP DocBlock style](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/docblocks.html).

Comment: Nitpick: in Python, it's not a coding style, it is part of the language syntax. A lone string literal as the first statement of a declaration is interpreted as an assignment to the instance variable `__doc__`.

Comment: Python's official syntax says otherwise. Python 2's [syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html), e.g.: `funcdef: 'def' NAME parameters ':' suite`. Nothing in `suite` mentions comments. While longer, Python 3's `funcdef` very similar. It's true most Python implementations recognize and support the convention, but however much [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), and the common idiom encourage it, docstring comments are entirely optional. Tons of Python code ignores the convention, yet runs just fine.

Comment: It's not a comment. It's a string literal. The special casing is documented in https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring

Comment: Yes, it is a string literal. Your assertion was that it was "part of the language syntax." It's not. The language syntax includes no such thing. PEP 8 and PEP 257 define Python's desired, idiomatic coding style and documentation conventions. Therefore, docstrings are part of Python's style and conventions, not its syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. So you are saying that a docstring is just a string literal like any other? It has no special semantics? But that's not the case: the string literal is not assigned to any variable, not returned, not passed as an argument to any function. It is completely unreferenced. It is created, immediately eligible for garbage collection, and immediately unreachable. An optimizing compiler could even omit it completely. But that is not the case: instead, it *is* being assigned to an attribute named `__doc__`, and even represented in the bytecode. Other string literals don't …

Comment: … behave the same way. When I write `print("Hello, World")`, the string object `"Hello, World"` doesn't get assigned to an attribute named `__doc__`. So, the language *does* treat some string literals which appear in certain special positions differently than other string literals. Those string literals *must* appear in *specific* syntactic locations, and then are bestowed specific non-standard semantics. That is pretty clearly a language feature.

Comment: I'm saying your assertion that docstrings are "part of the language syntax" is wrong, and obviously so if you read the language syntax definition. Now you're arguing a different point, about how it's treated semantically. I agree it's treated specially, in support of the PEP 8 and PEP 257 conventions. Still doesn't make it part of the language syntax. And, other than supporting REPLs, debuggers, and occasional introspection code, has almost no impact on code semantics or program output.